# How to bring a value to SharePoint dialog

Tags: dialog-framework, modal-dialog

How can I bring a value to SharePoint Dialog to bind data.
I call the dialog like this

```
<input type="button" value="<%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Id"] %>"   onclick="javascript:Open()" />
```

The script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //User Defined Function to Open Dialog Framework
    function Open() {

        var strPageURL = '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/View.aspx") %>';
        OpenCustomDialogWithRefresh(strPageURL, 650, 400, "Add Document Type");
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

JS

```
function OpenCustomDialogWithRefresh(dialogUrl, dialogWidth, dialogHeight, dialogTitle, dialogAllowMaximize, dialogShowClose) {

var options = {
    url: dialogUrl,
    allowMaximize: dialogAllowMaximize,
    showClose: dialogShowClose,
    width: dialogWidth,
    height: dialogHeight,
    title: dialogTitle,
    dialogReturnValueCallback: Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback4)
};
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);}
```

I don't know how to bring the Id value to the View.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass it as a parameter to Open() function and then to OpenCustomDialogWithRefresh() function. You can pass it on as a query string parameter like:

strPageURL = strPageURL + '?id=" + idParam

You can access the query string parameter in View.aspx.

You can also pass it as args property of your options. Check this article: http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2010/11/17/using-the-dialog-framework-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Refer to this blog](http://www.sharepointdevelopment.me/2011/06/passing-data-to-and-from-sharepoint-modal-dialogs/)

Provide args to `options` which you pass to `ShowModalDialog` function. Then in modal dialog just retrieve the args through `window.frameElement.dialogArgs` You can pass simple values and whole objects.